# Simple URL query parse and re-direct

Tags: javascript, regex, url, redirect

I'm looking for help doing what I think should be pretty simple to do in JavaScript. I have a query string in the format of **9SJN25-30-10** that I want to be able to pass to one URL (e.g., www.example.com/?q=9SJN25-30-10. I want to be able to automatically parse that URL and re-direct to another URL in the following format: www.domain.com/journal/year**9**/issue**25**/article**30**/page**10**/ where the numbers are pulled from the query string and inserted as shown in the previous example.

It would be especially nice if the re-direct script would disallow any characters or symbols other than letters, numbers, and dashes and would display an error message if the input query is not strictly in the format of **#SJN#-#-#** (with # representing a number that is one or more digits long and the letters SJN are hardcoded).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Show us what have you tried so far. Read the http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: `/(\d+)SJN(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/` this regex should help you. It extracts the different values you want from the string.

Comment: What is the point of being redirected to one URL with a querystring that then redirects to another with that folder path? Why not just go directly to that folder path?

Comment: Because the citations are in a particular format (#SJN#-#-#) and I don't have control over the final destination website. What I'm trying to do is make a way to easily go to the final destination using a link based on the citation. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Heru-Luin Thanks, that's helpful. I've never really understood Regex.